# Where can I find the Sanskrit work "Jnyana Bhagwat" attributed to Mareechi

Tags: scripture, ganesha

In the Vinayaka Rahasyam Volume IV Part B there is a mention of Jnyana Bhagwat having been told by Mareechi the mind son of Brahma to Mudgal Mahamuni.